# Microsoft SQL Server memory utilization

Tags: sql-server, memory, utilization

I'm confused about memory utilization of SQL Server. Before migration I've been using 2GB RAM and memory usage was a 1.87GB. After I migrated my server with 16GB physical memory. But it's not approximately 1.87GB it will be 5Gb or higher than. SQL Server data hasn't changed.

Here is memory usage of my current server. Do you have any idea about this? PLS

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It uses more memory *because it can*. It's used for caching purposes; indexes, query plans, data.

You can limit the memory usage in the [Server Memory Server Configuration Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx)

Comment: Ok. Thanks Simon. So is it right? SQL Server memory utilization (caching, indexes, query plans and other ) depends on memory capacity?

Comment: Of course, it will never use more physical memory than you have available. You can configure both lower and upper bounds in the server configuration options.